# setOnItemSelectedListener does not work with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have:

```
class MainBottomNavigation : BottomNavigationView {

    private var navController: NavController? = null
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    init {
        setUpListeners()
    }

    private fun setUpListeners() {
        setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.fragment_navigation_one-> {
                    ...
                    true
                }
                R.id.fragment_navigation_two-> {
                    ...
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
        setOnItemReselectedListener {
        }
    }

    fun setupWithNavController(navController: NavController) {
        this.navController = navController
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

}
```

In the AndroidManifest I have:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/main_navigation" />
        </activity>
```

and in the layout of the main activity I have:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />
```

While the `OnItemReselectedListener` is called and everything works as expected that means that nothing happens on reselecting, the `OnItemSelectedListener` is never called.

The reason why I need the listener is that by default the BottomNavigationView creates new fragments and replaces the previous ones instead of reusing the fragment that are already there. I have seen people suggesting to create instances of the Fragments and then reuse them in the listener.
What I wanted to try was to use the listener to check whether the Fragment is already there and eventually hide the current (to be able to show it again later) and show the new one.

Comment: If you are using a `NavHostFragment`, then it is already doing the only thing that is supported. If you are using Navigation 2.4.0 or higher, then your bottom nav already supports [multiple back stacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134), which means the [state your fragment saves](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) is already restored automatically. You never, ever should be 'reusing' fragments or anything like that.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you. I switched to the new version but the Fragments are still recreated all the times. Something else is wrong but at least I know that it should work

Comment: Again, recreation is never a problem if you've [saved your state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) - you'll be in the exact state you were before.

Comment: I have an exoplayer view that needs to prepare playing. If the Fragment is recreated I need to prepare the player again and the result is a bit clunky